# Interactive Europe map R Shiny with ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, ggmap

For a group project, I wanted to create a interactive Europe map, based on this data set: https://ourworldindata.org/causes-of-death.
I have manage to create this map, which will display the number of deaths caused by drowning in 2019 in Europe. But I would like to create an interactive map where the user could enter the cause of deaths for example HIV or Fire, so that the map could display it. I have tried to use an input but it doesn't work and shows me this error message : "Error in : Discrete value supplied to continuous scale". I know that the cause of this issue is the fact that the parameter size is a int but the input a char.
Unfortunalty I don't know how to correct this issue :(

Can anyone help me with it?
Have a nice day,
AM.

```
library("maptools")
library(rgdal)
library(maps)
library("jsonlite")
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggmap)

rowdb <- read.csv("annual-number-of-deaths-by-cause.csv", sep = ';')
rowdb <- select(rowdb, -X.1, -X)
        
europe <- c(left = -12, bottom = 35, right = 30, top = 63)
map_E <- get_stamenmap(europe, zoom = 5,"toner-lite")
ggmap(map_E)
    
#On va cr?er une variable contenant les noms des pays du continent puis pour une date donn?e
#qu'on pourra aussi demander ? l'utilisateur de s?lectionner on affichera la carte du 
#continent et la cause choisies
Europe_E <- c("Albania", "Andorra", "Armenia", "Austria","Azerbaijan","Belarus",
                  "Belgium", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bulgaria", "Croatia","Cyprus",
                  "Czechia", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Georgia",
                  "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Italy", 
                  "Kazakhstan","Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Moldova", "Monaco",
                  "Montenegro", "Netherlands","North Macedonia", "Norway", "Poland", "Portugal",
                  "Romania", "Russia", "San Marino","Serbia", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", 
                  "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Turkey", "Ukraine", "United Kingdom")
    
    #Fonction pour avoir la latitude et longitude des pays
    if (!(require(jsonlite))) install.packages("jsonlite")
    mygeocode <- function(adresses){
      # adresses est un vecteur contenant toutes les adresses sous forme de chaine de caracteres
      nominatim_osm <- function(address = NULL){
        ## details: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim
        ## fonction nominatim_osm propos?e par D.Kisler
        if(suppressWarnings(is.null(address)))  return(data.frame())
        tryCatch(
          d <- jsonlite::fromJSON(
            gsub('\\@addr\\@', gsub('\\s+', '\\%20', address),
                 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/@addr@?format=json&addressdetails=0&limit=1')
          ), error = function(c) return(data.frame())
        )
        if(length(d) == 0) return(data.frame())
        return(c(as.numeric(d$lon), as.numeric(d$lat)))
      }
      tableau <- t(sapply(adresses,nominatim_osm))
      colnames(tableau) <- c("lon","lat")
      return(tableau)
    }

        latlon_E <- mygeocode(Europe_E)
        #is(lalo)
        dat_E <- as.data.frame(latlon_E)
        DAT_E <- rowdb
        DAT_E$Year <- year(as.Date(DAT_E$Year, format = "%Y"))
        DAT_E <- DAT_E[
          as.character(DAT_E$Year) %in% c("2019"), ]
        DAT_E <- DAT_E[
          DAT_E$Entity %in% Europe_E, ]
        
        ggmap(map_E, extent = "device") + 
          geom_point(data = DAT_E, aes(x = dat_E$lon , y =dat_E$lat, color = Europe_E, size = Drowning), alpha = 0.5) +
          geom_text(data = DAT_E, aes(x = dat_E$lon, y = dat_E$lat, label = Drowning), color = "black", size = 3.7) +
          scale_size_continuous(range = c(6, 12)) + theme(legend.position = "none")+
          facet_wrap(~ Year)
```

Comment: It is not reproducible. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Hi @TarJae, I've updated the post ^^ But I can't post the .csv data set (idk how to...)

Comment: To make the map interactive the way you intend, you would probably need to make a shiny app or a flex dashboard that used crosstalk and leaflet.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Ok so if I understood correctly I need to make a new app but with leaflet and crosstalk? Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: usually, these errors come from your `scale_size_continuous` in the ggplot, because you select a discrete variable and use a `_continuous` scale

Comment: @denis so I should replace scale_size_continuous by scale_continuous?

Comment: nope, `scale_size_discrete`, but it depends on the variable you are potting

Comment: @denis I am trying to plot with an input which contains the names of the different causes of deaths (colnames)

Comment: `scale_size_discrete` for categorical variables, `scale_size_continuous` for numerical ones. But you will need a shiny app and leaflet anyway for the interactive part

Comment: @denis I see.. I already have the shiny, I just need to figure out how leaflet works.